# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, shell, subprocess

Let's say I have this snippet

```
list_command = 'mongo --host {host} --port {port} ' \
             '--username {username} --password {password} --authenticationDatabase {database} < {path}'


def shell_exec(cmd: str):
    import subprocess
    p = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
    return p
```

Let's say these are the commands I'm trying to run on mongo

```
use users
show collections
db.base.find().pretty()
```

If format the string **list_command** with the appropriate values and pass it to the function with **shell=True**, it works fine. But I'm trying to avoid it for security purposes.
If I call it with **shell=False**, I get the following error:

> 2020-08-31T14:08:49.291+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @./mongo/user-01-09-2020:1:4
> failed to load: ./mongo/user-01-09-2020
> 253

Answer (score 1):

Your `list_command` *is* a shell command: in particular, it includes input redirection (via `< {path}`), which is a syntactic feature of the shell. To use it you *need* `shell=True`.

If you don’t want to use `shell=True`, you need to change the way you construct the argument (separate arguments need to be passed as separate items of a list rather than as a single string), and you need to pass the script into the standard input via an explicit pipe, by setting its `input` parameter:

```
cmd = ['mongo', '--host', '{host}', '--port', …]
subprocess.run(cmd, input=mongodb_script)
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my day !

Answer (score 0):

Using input raised the following error: *TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input'*.

I ended up doing the following:

```
import subprocess
def shell_exec(cmd: str, stdin=None):
  with open(stdin, 'rb') as f:
      return subprocess.call(cmd.split(), stdin=f)
```

Comment: My mistake, you need to use `run` instead of `call`.

Comment: Your code can be simplified by replacing the `try` block with `with`. But the entire code assumes that the MongoDB script is written to a file by the caller, which strikes me as inconvenient unless these files actually already exist. The variable `p` is also unnecessary; return the result of `subprocess.call` directly. And using `cmd.split()` is almost certainly a bad idea. What if some argument contains spaces? It’s a better idea to never store the command inside a single string in the first place, use a list from the get-go.